# when I add a movie I need to update the count on the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, typescript, kendo-ui

- I am trying to pass the value from the method sportsScore in ts file to the HTML
- each time when I add a movie I need to update the count on the link
- right now its taking from some place. {{contract.docsCount}} movies
- when I upload a movie the _songsMorning.length value increases but not sure how to pass it into HTML
- providing relevant code below
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing relevant code below and whole code in the fiddle since my code is so big https://jsfiddle.net/mb9ccs5z/

```or-tag-here
<div class="waterDocInfoHolder">
                <div class="waterIconHolder borderBottom0Imp">
                    <span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="waterDocInfo">          
                        <span class="fa fa-file-text-o"></span>
                        <span class="commonLink" (click)="moviesClicked(contract);">&nbsp;{{contract.docsCount}} movies</span> | Last Modified: {{contract.dateUpdate | date : "MM/dd/yyyy" }} &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-clock-o">{{contract.dateUpdate | date : " h:mm a" }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```
sportsScore(evt, dropValue) {

    let todayDate = this.todayDate();
    let grid = $('#financialmoviesGrid').data('kendoGrid');
    let _playerMarks = grid.dataSource;
    let pageSize = _playerMarks.pageSize();
    let gridLength = _playerMarks._data.length;
    let filename;

    if (this.fileSelect == null || this.fileSelect == "") {
      _playerMarks.insert(gridLength, {
        "movieId": "",
        "movieName": filename,
        "movieType": this.movieType,
        "movieData": "",
        "notes": "",
        "notesId": null,
        "elfDocID": "",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000/upload",
        "date": todayDate,
        "addedByName": $(".loggedUserName").text(),
        "userID": "",
        "operationType": "create"
      });
    } else {

      let temparry = [];
      let attributes = this.sportsService.getSeesionStorageValue();
      let lastIndex = this.fileSelect.lastIndexOf(".");
      if (lastIndex >= 0) {
        filename = this.fileSelect; //.substring(lastIndex,0);
      }
      if (filename.length > 99) {

        $(".kendoContent").text('movie name cannot exceed 100 characters. Please rename and try again.');
        let newdialog = $("#greaterAlert").data("kendoWindow").center().open();

        $("#greaterAlertOK").unbind().click(function() {
          newdialog.close();
        });

        return false;
      }

      var fileSize = 0;
      fileSize = fileSize / 1048576; //size in mb 


      if (attributes) {
        this.loggedUserName = attributes.user_attributes.DisplayName[0];
      }

      let k = _playerMarks._data.length;

      _playerMarks.insert(k, {
        "movieId": "",
        "movieName": filename,
        "movieType": this.movieType,
        "movieData": "",
        "notes": "",
        "notesId": null,
        "elfDocID": "",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000/upload",
        "date": todayDate,
        "addedByName": $(".loggedUserName").text(),
        "userID": "",
        "operationType": "create"
      });

      let data = {
        "data": [{
          "movieId": "",
          "movieName": filename,
          "movieType": this.movieType,
          "movieData": "",
          "notes": "",
          "notesId": null,
          "elfDocID": "",
          "url": "http://localhost:3000/upload",
          "date": todayDate,
          "addedByName": $(".loggedUserName").text(),
          "userID": "",
          "operationType": "create"
        }]
      };

      temparry.push(data)
      let movieData = {};
      movieData["gridData"] = data;

      this.dragDrop = "";
      this.dragDrop = this.clearBtn;

      $("#attachmovieBrowseBtn").val('');
      this.fileSelect = "";

      let _songsMorning = _playerMarks.data();
      for (let d = 0; d < _songsMorning.length; d++) {
        if (_songsMorning[d].isElfDoc == true && _songsMorning[d].elfDocID == "") {
          this.gridkendo.enableSavemovie(false);
        }

      }

    }
    $('.addELFmovieForm').hide();
    let permissionDto = "";
    let functionalList = "";

    if (true) {

      console.log();

      let currentData = _playerMarks._data;
      let records = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < currentData.length; i++) {
        if (currentData[i].movieId == "") {
          this.dataPush(records, currentData[i], "Create");
        }
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < _playerMarks._destroyed.length; i++) {
        this.dataPush(records, _playerMarks._destroyed[i], 'Delete');
      }

      this.sportsService.getResponse("financials/v1/movie/", "post", records)
      .subscribe(data => {

          if (data.code == 'S001') {
            if (this.isNavigate) {
              this.navigateCheck(false);
            } else {
            }
          } else {
            this.navigateCheck(true);
          }


        },
        err => {
          this.navigateCheck(true);
        }
      );
    }

  }
```

Comment: You are essentially handing us your application and asking someone to debug it.  Try to simplify and isolate the problem first.  If you're still stuck, feel free to return with a more specific question.

Comment: @axlj thanks for your reply.. I debugged the code...not sure how to pass the value from sportsScore method to my html tag... can you please help me